# Faster operations on a large string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Let's say I have a large random string like so...

```
_W:,aLH#J&A4=IY;    ?RVUc?W+</59JG4WSGW6G6$QEHQ:>,*b60$BYR=D=-^8-4(0    "??YaI0Y    SD9 FJ;MZ,V+'S]0:9L%;#a23cO%bMY[O6^S;ULRV2XA    8&  6_5W21E+Y$RYY$K"Q.0J+:cJC301M3H![7
L%K
Q5(4I9/9DAFR,-8<BJ=4H>9M,OX!.A4aQ:
BK<a"1ID.=U-US`R_])>GG)UL\!G?U$RRG_
HcW 3;<U5`X.?:6K@H*ZD3[M!ZU#KJXbE<Y*VV#ZYU#=]?Q
5:a^]#T

XRT.V]>57#W"U1=K$X]&JIY)::AE :K'7!_DV1B>SJ9D_`]>aC"N'US$;CaHK<N#-
"cJ,%RT)!J0DLFUb[[FOCQX(/.E3#
U
L$("+$) ;TDZ
;T#XS-'6U4`UKZ0a85D&+a]I.C/-7LDM_#/aS9OYA!#^G1II*XKL`;c
ES62Wa^=BQHK6E&A .X+4FDZ:   3UOaJ
#1<BY:;@D:`^`8E\-[9&7PXPH

... a lot more
```

And I want to do an operation over the entire string, like inserting newlines after semi-colons.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string buffer = "";
    std::string line = "";
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        buffer += line + std::string("\n");

    auto it = std::find(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), ';');
    while (it != buffer.end())
    {
        buffer.insert(it, '\n');
        it = std::find(it+1, buffer.end(), ';');
    }
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This obviously takes too long. What should I do? Would it be better if I chunked them into smaller strings? If not, how can I make this faster?

**EDIT**

I'm an idiot. I had an infinite loop at this line here

```
- it = std::find(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), ';');
+ it = std::find(it+1, buffer.end(), ';');
```

Although I still give credit to the person who provided a nice answer.

Comment: well, it wont go much faster if you want to insert stuff in between. You can insert at the end or the front very fast... the rest is just find/search work and takes more time the larger the document gets... even for well formatted files/strings

Comment: What are you going to do with the string in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I normally very much prefer using the C++ standard library, in this particular case I think good-old-C-style code might be the better option.

If the processing that you're going to do just depends on interpreting a character at a time (e.g. inserting newlines after semicolons) then reading in one character at a time and then writing out one (or two, if the character is a semicolon and has to be followed by an additional newline) will be very fast if both input and output are buffered.

If the processing of character `n` depends only on characters `1` to `n`, then a similar approach would work -- it would just be necessary to either pre-decide the processing action based on the characters seen so far or to store all the preceding characters so that the action can be decided based on all of characters `1` to `n`.

In neither of these cases would it be necessary to insert characters into the middles of strings and therefore have to shift large chunks of memory around.

Only if the processing on character `n` (e.g. whether or not to insert a character after that character) depended on characters that followed character `n` would it be necessary to read in all the text before processing it. Even then, the amount of memory that would have to be shifted around for all the inserted characters could be reduced to no more than `N` characters, where `N` is the total length of the processed string (with additional characters if required), by using a function like the following:

```
void copyWithProcessing (char *from, char *to) {
    while (*from) {
        // do any pre-processing
        *to++ = *from++;
        // do any post-processing
     }
 }
```

This assumes we can pre-allocate enough space for the character array pointed at by `to` because we know in advance how many extra characters will be needed due to the processing that is about to happen. Alternatively, if we don't need to store the resulting string in memory, we could just write it out character by character after the processing on each character is complete, which would mean we would not have to allocate any space for it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resort to C-style programming for this, in C++ you could use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) for the result and insert the newlines immediately on each line you read:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        auto prev = 0;
        auto pos = line.find(';');
        while (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            ++pos;
            buffer.write(&line[prev],pos-prev);
            buffer.put('\n');
            prev = pos;
            pos = line.find(';',pos);
        }
        buffer.write(&line[prev],line.size()-prev);
        buffer.put('\n');
    }

    std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```